# How do you craete a django rest framework ListCreateAPIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement functionality to upload a batch of records into a database using drf. 
This is my class in my api view.

```
class BatchRecordModelViewSet(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    This is an API view to insert a batch of item counts.
    """
    serializer_class = serializers.BatchRecordSerializer
    queryset = models.Record.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = request.data
        some_data = request.user.profile.profile_id
        for rec in data:
            rec.update(some_data=some_data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is my serializer that I am importing:

```
class BatchRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = RecordSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Record
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3', etc...)
```

Here is the snippet from my urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from rest_framework import routers
from my_app.api import viewSet1, viewSet2, viewSet3


router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'endpoint1', viewSet1.BatchRecordModelViewSet, base_name='endpoint1')
router.register(r'endpoint2', viewSet2.SomeOtherViewSet, base_name='endpoint2')
router.register(r'endpoint3', viewSet3.SomeOtherViewSet, base_name='endpoint3')


urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

The urls for endpoint 2 and 3 are working just fine, it's just endpoint 1 that keeps giving me issues.

Comment: But what is your question? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I keep getting the following error thrown when I try to run the app: extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: type object 'BatchItemCountModelViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Comment: @Jasonca1 Can you add your corresponding `urls.py` code snippet?

Comment: The error seems to correspond to `BatchItemCountModelViewSet` but you've not shown the code for that?