# Django REST framework: type object X has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Ubuntu LTS, Python 3.6.x, Django 2.2.1, DRF 3.9.3

I started with the DRF quickstart. Worked fine.

Jumped into the [DRF tutorial, step 3 on using generic class based views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#using-generic-class-based-views) I'm getting this error when trying `manage.py runserver`

```
File "/home/ubuntu/src/rasi/rais/instances/urls.py", line 11, in <module>
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/managed-research-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 125, in
urls
    self._urls = self.get_urls()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/managed-research-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 386, in
get_urls
    urls = super(DefaultRouter, self).get_urls()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/managed-research-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 284, in
get_urls
    routes = self.get_routes(viewset)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/managed-research-prod/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 200, in
get_routes
    extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: type object 'InstanceList' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

I've only made the minimal changes to my code base in order to implement the recommendations by the tutorial.

It's not obvious what I've done wrong, and there's not a lot of information around `get_extra_actions` when I read the [ListCreateAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) guide, and not a lot that seems obviously comparable when looking elsewhere

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users',views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'instances',views.InstanceList)                                                                            

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.dash, name='dash'),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField()
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Instance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    flavour = models.CharField(choices=FLAVOUR_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    os = models.IntegerField(choices=OS_CHOICES)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    allocation_manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='manager')
    allocation_notes = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    requested_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='requestor')
```

**serializer.py**

```
# Serializers define the API representation.
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):                                                               
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')

class InstanceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    allocation_manager = UserSerializer()
    requested_by = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Instance
        fields = ('name', 'flavour', 'hostname', 'allocation_manager','requested_by')
```

**views.py**

```
# Serializer Views
# ViewSets define the view behavior.

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class InstanceList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Instance.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InstanceSerializer
```

Note/Edit: I've found [some questions, but few solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490405/how-do-you-craete-a-django-rest-framework-listcreateapiview).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Basically you are trying to register a non-viewset(here `InstanceList` a view, not a viewset) to router. Instead of this, you can simply use it in urls like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users',views.UserViewSet)                                                                         

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.dash, name='dash'),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/instances/', views.InstanceList.as_view(), name="instances"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Basic is that we create view in views.py extend or inherit the**  
(CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin) and 
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView,RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
**Like as**

```
 class CartViewSet(CreateModelMixin,RetrieveModelMixin,DestroyModelMixin ):
       queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related("items","items__product").all()
       serializer_class = CartSerializer
       (........)
```

But we have to **import GenericViewSet from rest_framework.Viewset**

```
class CartViewSet(CreateModelMixin,RetrieveModelMixin,DestroyModelMixin,GenericViewSet ):
     queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related("items","items__product").all()
     serializer_class = CartSerializer
     (........)
```

error that prompt should not be occur or gone using this just add **GenericViewSet class** In view class

Answer (score 0):

The error

> AttributeError: type object 'InstanceList' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

suggests that the view you're trying to use with the router is not a viewset or doesn't have the expected methods for a viewset. A viewset typically has methods like create, get, delete, list etc and yours has none.

You have options 2 of resolving this:

1. You'll have to implement the create, update, retrieve and destroy methods in your view e.g

   ```
   class InstanceList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        # Your implementation for list, create, retrieve, update, destroy, etc.
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserSerializer
   ```
2. in your urls.py don't use routers, use the normal url patterns

Answer (score 0):

In your settings `urls.py` file, you could do this:

```
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
]
```

Then in your api app urls.py file, you can do this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users',views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/instances/', views.InstanceList.as_view(), name="instances"),
]
urlpatterns += router.urls
```